# Running a Brother HL-3040CN on Windows 98. No problems, right?

Tags: network-printer, windows-98, brother-printer

My client insists on using Windows 98. AFAICT, there should be no problem attaching a Brother HL-3040CN to the network and expecting it to handle the PCL5 and Postscript sent from Windows and DOS programs. Is that the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory there will be no problems if you can get the network connectivity you want, but the oldest driver officially available from Brother is for XP so, as you suggest, you will have to use a 'generic' driver which may not support all the features of the printer - but for that age of printer this will probably not be an issue.